# Is it possible to have a MySQL column containing multiple values as foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mariadb

I am learning MySQL and have MariaDB installed in Fedora 19.

I have a scenario where I require a column to contain multiple values in order to reduce possible redundancy of column allocation.

In the example below, is it possible to have each value in the `tags` column of the `log` table reference the `tag_id` column in the `tags` table?

**users**

```
user_id        |
1              |
```

**activities**

```
activitity_id  |
1
```

**log**

```
user_id        |    activity_id    | tags
1              |    1              | 1,3,5 # multiple foreign keys?
```

**tags**

```
tag_id         |
1              |
2              |
3              |
4              |
5              |
```

If it is not possible, could anyone provide the logic for the most feasible solution based on the data scenario above?

**Similar Questions:**

[Are multiple foreign keys in a single field possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094170/are-multiple-foreign-keys-in-a-single-field-possible)

[MySQL foreign key having multiple (conditional) possible values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653893/mysql-foreign-key-having-multiple-conditional-possible-values)

[it is possible to reference one column as multiple foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547276/it-is-possible-to-reference-one-column-as-multiple-foreign-keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not wish to make up a "middle man" table for linking the two tables you can have a comma separated value in the field, you would just need to use the `find_in_set` mysql function when doing queries

**USING find_in_set**

```
SELECT
   log.user_id, log.activity_id, log.tags,
   GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name) as taggedNames //This assumes there is a field called `name` in tags table
FROM
   log
LEFT JOIN tags
ON
   FIND_IN_SET(tags.tag_id,log.tags)
GROUP BY
   log.activity_id
```

GROUP_CONCAT will group together a field and separate them by a deliminator, default is `,`

Comment: `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'log.user_id' in 'field list'`

Comment: @user1063287 forgot to add the `log` table to the `FROM` clause

Comment: `Empty set (0.01 sec)` - do i need to add further definition to the above query?  The contents of record 1 in log.tags is `'1,2'` (VARCHAR(30)).

Comment: It might be that you need a left join instead, (edited answer to show), my server is down so i cant test properly

Comment: Both the `LEFT JOIN ON` and `log, tags WHERE` solutions are producing a result.  The only anomaly I can see, in both solutions, is that where `log.tags` are ouput as `1,2` the corresponding `tags.name` are in what seems to be the reverse order ie `tag_name_two, tag_name_one`.  But I will try and troubleshoot this, perhaps it is an ORDER BY thing.

Comment: Yea if you want them ordered you will have to do an order by on the tag names. But do it like `order by log.activity_id, tags.name` or similar order on some part of the main row as otherwise if you do it simply by tags.name the log results may be out of order